# Why "White Space" not detected in a string in C#?

Tags: regex, whitespace, c#-2.0

I am getting very confused having this error. Below are the 2 strings I am comparing and they look exactly same in the open eyes. But when I tried to compare them in C# Code OR MS Excel, the result is "Mismatch".

```
1st: Frillestads_församling_Länsräkenskaper efter 1917. Mantalslängder 1918-1991 Special 99

2nd: Frillestads_församling_Länsräkenskaper efter 1917. Mantalslängder 1918-1991 Special 99
```

Even when I tried to split them in a string array using single space (' '), the 1st line wasn't splitted.

Here is the C# code:

```
    private void btnFindMismatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = FormattedString(txtFirstValue.Text);
        string value2 = FormattedString(txtSecondValue.Text);

        bool isMismatchFound = false;

        string[] value1Array = value1.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] value2Array = value2.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < value1Array.Length; i++)
        {
            if(value1Array[i].Equals(value2Array[i]) == false)
            {
                lblResult.Text = string.Format("Mismatch in index: {0}; 1st Char: {1}; 2nd Char: {2}", i, value1Array[i], value2Array[i]);
                isMismatchFound = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isMismatchFound)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "No Mismatch";
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Complete");
    }

    private string FormattedString(string value)
    {
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
        value = regex.Replace(value, @" ");

        return value;
    }
```

I then tried to check the 1st value in notepad++ and then found that, the 1st string did not contain any "White Space".

Please see below screen shots for more clearer view.

[image: C# Code output]

[image: Notepad++ Search output]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that those aren't normal spaces (`0x20`) but perhaps non-breakable spaces (`0xA0`). If you use the universal whitespace shorthand `\s` instead of a standard space character, it should work.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}", options); // for example
```

Note that `\s` will also match newlines, tabs and other whitespace - so perhaps you want to make the regex more specific, depending on which space character is actually being used (Notepad++ probably has a hexadecimal mode that will allow you to check which one it is exactly):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ \xa0]{2,}", options);
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggested regular expressions, but still the 1st line isn't breaking and remains same as previous.

Comment: I can't reproduce that here - can you check the ASCII value of the "spaces" in your first string? Notepad++ appears to need a [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/) to do that.

Comment: when I select the SPACE before "efter" and click on the "HEX" button in notepad++, it is showing "a0" in highlighted color. Also, it is showing a DOT (.) between "skaper" & "efter" like "skaper.efter" under the Dump column. But when I select a DOT (.) and view its HEX value, it is showing "2e" and NOT "a0". I did not understand what this mean.

Comment: @V.P.Verma: The dot NP++ is showing under the DUMP column is simply there to visualize that there is a special character instead of a normal space (an actual ASCII dot has the character value `0x2e`). So those spaces are in fact non-breakable spaces. The second regex `[ \xa0]` should match those. Don't forget to switch on the Regular Expression option in the Search/Replace dialog.

Comment: Tim, Yes. In NP++, using the regex "\xa0", I can replace the non-breakable spaces with other char. But in C# code above, when I use your second regex, it still not breaking. Can you help me on that please?

Comment: @V.P.Verma: The regex, as you designed it, breaks only if there are at least two of those whitespace characters (`{2,}`) - if you also want to break on single characters, use `[ \xa0]+` instead.

Comment: you can try in c# to use `[\r|\n|\s]` as the splitter instead of space.

Comment: @ghoulfolk: `\s` already contains `\n` and `\r`. Also, `|` means a literal `|` character if it's inside a character class.